# What is the density of nitrogen at standard conditions?

Tags: ideal-gas

I find diverging answers to what the density of nitrogen at standard conditions is.
By standard conditions I mean T=273.15 K and P=1 atm (=1.01325 bar).

Different sources state:

- Wikipedia : 1.2506 g/L
- Fluidat : 1.250 g/L
- NIST : 1.2504 g/L
- When I use ideal gas law : 1.2498 g/L (using molar mass as 28.0134 g/mol and gas constant as 8.31446261815324*10^3 J/(K mol)

Which one is more correct and why ?

Comment: The first 3 values probably rely either on measurements either on values provided by some of  real gas state equations. Try to calculate density from the van der Waals equation, probably by numerical finding the  root of the cubic equation.

Comment: Nothing is "more" correct. Something is correct or isn't.

Comment: Looks identical to me.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar As this is science, not math, with errors, assumptions, conditions, fuzziness and uncertainties, it is not so much black and white. Gramatically, you are right though, like there is nothing more optimal than optimal.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar not true in most sciences, and definitely not true in chemistry.

Comment: The deviation is in order of one-ten thousandths. So, I'd say, the values are pretty much equal.

Answer (score 1):

- *One possibility* for differences in measured density of an element is isotopic variation. For example, [sulfur isotope abundance may vary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_sulfur), depending if the element is derived from soil, from sulfide minerals or as the native element from a volcanic vent. [Nitrogen has two common stable isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_nitrogen): <sup>14</sup>N and <sup>15</sup>N. It is *possible* that the measurement of density varied because of natural variation.
- However, it is *possible* the density varied because [the definition of "Standard Temperature and Pressure" (STP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure) has changed over time (e.g., 101.325 kPa pre-1982, 100 kPa afterwards).
- It is *possible* the density measurements varied because [the definition of mass has changed over time.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram#Timeline_of_previous_definitions)
- It is *possible* the density measurements varied because of experimental error.

So if the discrepancies are a cause for concern in your work, check the *source given for each measurement* to help explain the differences.